# Day's fixed point theorem

Tags: group-theory, locally-convex-spaces, amenability

**Day's fixed point theorem** (Theorem 1.3.1; *Lecture on amenability*; **Volker Runde**)

Let $G$ be a locally compact group. The following are equivalent:

1. $G$ is amenable.
2. If $G$ acts (from left side) affinely on a compact, convex subset $K$ of a locally convex vector space $E$, *i.e.*
   $$g\cdot(tx+(1-t)y)=t(g\cdot x)+(1-t)(g\cdot y)\qquad (g\in G,x,y\in K,t\in [0,1])$$ 
   such that 
   $$G\times K\to K,\qquad (g,x)\mapsto g\cdot x$$
   is separately continuous, then there is $x\in K$ such that $g\cdot x=x$ for all $g\in G$.

**My question:**

If $G$ is discrete amenable and $G$ acts form both sides affinely and
$$g\cdot(a\cdot h)=(g\cdot a)\cdot h,\qquad (g,h\in G, a\in K),$$
and 
$$e\cdot a=a\cdot e=a, \qquad (a\in K),$$
where $e\in G$ is identity of $G$; 
then could we say that, there is $x\in K$ such that $x\cdot g=g\cdot x=x$ ??

If it is not true in general, which conditions can assure that it properly (I need infinite group)?

Comment: Your question us equivalent to one about two affine  commuting left actions, that is, about action of $G^2$. But the direct product of two amenable groups is again as amenable, hence, you have a 2-sided fixed point as required.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As Moishe Kohan commented, this follows from the fact that $G^2$ is amenable if $G$ is. However, one does not even need to know this fact and can verify it directly using Day's fixed point theorem:

Let $\alpha_g(a)=g\cdot a$ and $\beta_h(a)=a\cdot h^{-1}$. Let $K'$ be the set of fixed points of $\alpha$, which is non-empty by (ii). Moreover, it is easy to verify that $K'$ is convex and closed inside $K$, hence compact. Since $\beta_h\alpha_g=\alpha_g\beta_h$, the action $\beta$ restricts to an action on $K'$. Again, by (ii), $\beta$ will have a fixed point in $K'$, which is then a common fixed point of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.